# Laravel 5 Convert Date String to Desired Date Format

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have a set of dates with different formats as below

```
3 Mar 2020
Mar 3, 2020
A1 -- this is obviously not a date but how can I escape to convert this to date format? 
1I
```

Code below doesn't work with `A1` or `1I`.

```
if (Carbon::createFromFormat("d M Y", $item)) {
    return "valid"; 
    //do my things
}
//if it's not date, then just ignore
```

Any shortest way to convert the correct date to my date format `Y-m-d`?
And how can I escape from converting `A1` and `1I`? These lines should be ignored when comes to check the date format.

Comment: show your some code please.

Comment: @Siddharth added

Comment: For `A1` and `1I` what do you want the result be? a null value or just ignore this row? Anyway, you can use exception handing (`try{}catch{}`) to achieve it: put Carbon::createFromFormat("d M Y", $item) in the try section, if thrown error, will be caught as a exception, and you can ignore it or return a null value in catch section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$string = '3 Mar 2020';
if (strtotime($string)) {
    return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($string);
}
```

Comment: thank you! i tweaked a bit by checking if the input is not numeric as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use toggle script to change the date format:

Use `strtotime()` and `date()`:

```
$originalDate = "2010-03-21";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = 'Mar 3, 2020'; //

$carbon = Carbon::parse($date);

$desiredFormat = 'd/m/Y';

$formattedString = $carbon->format($desiredFormat);
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: this isn't working with my example input "A1". it will return - Exception with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (A1) at position 1 (1): Unexpected character'